# Replace column values with Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to cycle through a csv and replace any values in a column named `Enabled` from `True` to `A`.

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq 'True'} --> what goes here to replace 'True' with 'A'?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Where-Object` acts like a filter, so the columns that get passed to the rest of the pipeline will *only* be the ones where `Enabled` is `True`; which will prevent you from including the others in your output file (I'm assuming you want to have a complete file at the end).

So I would recommend using `ForEach-Object` and then modifying based on a condition inside there, but still passing each object through (modified or not):

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Enabled -eq 'True') {
        $_.Enabled = 'A'
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv .\test-modified.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Briantist's answer works just fine. If you really wanted to get crazy with it you could create an Excel `comobject`, select the workbook/sheet, then select the "enabled" entire column, snip out empty cells/column header, then loop through and essentially do the same thing as what briantist said, although this way you can do things like add conditional formatting, etc. Just depends what all you are trying to do

Comment: If we really want to go crazy, I'd say [Doug Finke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/110865/doug-finke)'s [Excel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) is even better than using the COM object (and doesn't require excel to be installed)!